# How to decode (shifting and xoring) a massive byte array in a fast way?

Tags: c#, performance, byte, decode

How to decode (shifting and xoring) a massive byte array in a fast way?
I need it for a file viewer application that opens the archive file and decodes the files inside and display them to the user. The files are encrypted with a byte shifting and xoring system. It is impossible for me to change the algorithm. Currently, I just read all the bytes and then run the Decode function on them.

The decode function that I currently use:

```
    byte[] DecodeVOQ(byte[] EncodedBytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < EncodedBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            EncodedBytes[i] ^= (byte)194;
            EncodedBytes[i] = (byte)((EncodedBytes[i] << 4) | (EncodedBytes[i] >> 4));
        }
        return EncodedBytes;
    }
```

**Edit:** I found out that the real performance problem is with displaying the text. Reading + Decoding is pretty fast.

Comment: That's not an "encryption" algorithm. That's slight obfuscation, that's all.

Comment: I can't really see how your comment is related to my question.

Comment: Is the current implementation not fast enough for your purposes?  You could try to do some clever things with unsafe code operating on 32-bit blocks, but I don't think you'll get much of a performance boost.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I have files in the archive larger than 20MB, it takes too long for the purpose of this application.

Comment: @lesderid: Just how fast does it need to be? If you're loading from the disk, that's where most of the cost will be. My laptop can decode 200MB in half a second... is that really too slow?

Comment: @Jon: You know what's funny? I found out that the real performance problem is with displaying the text. Reading + Decoding is pretty fast. I'll accept your answer though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One *possible* optimization would be to precompute the output for any input byte. So you'd have:

```
private static byte[] DecodedBytes = PrecomputeDecodedBytes();

public static byte[] DecodeVOQ(byte[] data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = DecodedBytes[data[i]];
    }
    return data;
}
```

It's quite possible that that will be slower than your existing bitshifting algorithm though. EDIT: I've just tried comparing this with the original bitshift but using a temporary local variable: they're about the same.

Have you benchmarked the current performance? Is it definitely too slow? In particular, loading the file from just about any storage medium will be much *much* slower than the cost of decoding. I've just tried this on my laptop - for 200MB of data, it takes about half a second. (EDIT: With Marcelo's answer, it takes *under* half a second.) Is that really too slow?

Would you be happy to use more than one processor? It's an embarrassingly parallelizable routine, after all. If you're using .NET 4, the TPL may well make this pretty simple.

I should emphasize again though that this *isn't* "encryption" - it's a mild form of obfuscation, in the same way that the base-64 encoding of a username/password for basic HTTP authentication is.

Comment: The lookup table was what I was thinking, but this might actually be slower (as you mention) by inducing cache misses.

Comment: +1 for TPL, if possible. Speed improvement would scale to processors, and hardware is cheap

Comment: I'll compare the speed of the original and your way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking a table driven approach would be faster, right? Since it's just bytes, and no byte depends on an adjacent byte, there are only 256 possible choices, so just lookup each one

Answer (score 2):

You might speed things up by using a temporary:

```
    byte b = EncodedBytes[i] ^ (byte)194;
    EncodedBytes[i] = (byte)((b << 4) | (b >> 4));
```

You might speed things up further by using `unsafe` and raw pointers, thus avoiding checked accesses (though I don't know if that's a consideration with current JIT optimisers).

Answer (score 0):

One approach to consider is to decode the data just as it's being displayed. That is, only decode a portion at a time. But I suspect you are just dumping the data to an edit control or something, which would not really make that an option. How are you displaying the data?

Other than that, I'm not sure how you'd speed it up too much.

Comment: @lesderid: I strongly suspect that the time taken to convert from binary to text and display it on the screen will *vastly* outweigh the decoding time. You're concentrating your efforts on the wrong bit of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Without .NET you'd be able to decode that 4 bytes in a time, but here, actually, the only one thing you can do is to precompute translation table.

Answer (score 0):

That's not xor, that's `shift` and `or`...

In assembly, that would be a single "rotate byte by 4" instruction.

BTW can't you decode it on demand? Decode the file in blocks, as you stream the file.

Comment: The previous line `EncodedBytes[i] ^= (byte)194;` has the xor.